# Executing cmd commands with complex output in c#

Tags: c#, shell, console-application

I often find myself using different commands on pc's to check stuff in the system and I wanted to basically create a small standalone exe that will execute all my common commands and give me the output of each of them without me entering them manually...
I want to note that I know this isn't the first question on google on the subject of executing a cmd command with c# but non fit my command requirements, for example many of them execute commands such as copy or move or make and non of them have a complex output, I want to execute for example the "sfc /scannow" command, which outputs a progress bar which measures the progress of course and a final output, the issue with that is I have tried many ways to attempt that but all failed, a shell execution works very well with opening another cmd windows and even requiring elevation but as soon as the progress bar ends and it displays the final output it crashes (and thus I can't see the final output), with shell execution off (executing via the main window) it either doesn't show the progress bar at all and just shows the final output, or shows nothing, or it does show the progress bar, but with each increment it's a new line which obviously doesn't look right...

this is my code:

```
public static void ExecuteCommand(string command) {
        Process prc = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Verb = "runas",
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Arguments = "/c" + command
        };
        prc.StartInfo = info;
        prc.Start();
        prc.WaitForExit();
        prc.Close();
    }
```

if anyone can think of a fix please do tell me, I have been stuck on this for about 3 days...

Comment: When you say you want the output of the program, do you want it to be logged in a file? If you want to see the progress bar of the executed cmd, AFAIK you should not use logging, but a terminal multiplexer. If you had this issue in ubuntu/bash shell, I would have told you about the screen package that allows you what you want. I'm not explored it myself, but a google search tells me that the powershell Connect-WSMAN would do the trick. However this is not C#, but a powershell script. I guess you can pass the Connect-WSMAN in your program to run in powershell.

Comment: @AshishJacob Well let me put it this way, the correct output would be to display the progress bar and then a string which says "the scan did not find any corruptions" or something like this, I would be comfortable with the progress bar being in a separate window like in this code, but this code exits before telling me what the scan found, if I could retrieve that string and then display it, it would be fine but I can't seem to do that. Another way would be to display everything in the main window, but I can't seem to get the progress bar to display properly...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the culprit was "/c", if I change it to "/K" the windows stays open until I close it manually like I wanted.